# Firebase data retrieval(Android Studio)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get "{ }" when I try to display data from Firebase (Android Studio),
Here's the code where I retrieve data
help me out I have tried all the YouTube tutorials nothing helped

```
package com.example.login;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


DatabaseReference fRef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mylistview = findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,list);
        fRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("students");
        mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("students");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    list.add(snap.getValue().toString());

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use specific properties for each child snapshot, you will have to extract their value separately. For example to display the `name` for each student:

```
list.add(snap.child("name").getValue(String.class));
```

---

You can also create a Java class to represent each student, and then use *that* to parse the properties from the snapshot. The simplest class for you could be:

```
public class Student {
  public String class_section, date_of_birth, roll_no, name, class_teacher;
}
```

With this simple class, you can then do:

```
Student student = snap.getValue(Student.class);
list.add(student.name+" - "+student.date_of_birth);
```

Comment: First method works fine! But for some second method is not working `Student student = snap.getValue(Student.class);
list.add(student.name+" - "+student.date_of_birth);` this is not working app crashes